# Generic method - "private <T> boolean (T[], T[])"

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I'm really new to generics in Java. I'm trying to create a simple method to compare two arrays that would be of the same type, but I want to use a generic method. I've attached a MWE below:

```
public class MWE {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] test1,test2;
    test1 = new int[2];
    test2 = new int[2];
    checkArray(test1,test2);
  }

  private <T> boolean checkArray(T[] check, T[] test) {
    if(check.length != test.length)
      return false;

    for(int i=0;i<check.length;i++)
      if(check[i]!=test[i])
        return false;

    return true;
  }
}
```

When I try to compile, I get:

```
MWE.java:6: <T>checkArray(T[],T[]) in MWE cannot be applied to (int[],int[])
    checkArray(test1,test2);
    ^
1 error
```

Comment: note that your method declaration can be simplified as `private boolean checkArray(Object[] check, Object[] test) {`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using Integer[] instead of int[].

**In more detail:**

Java Generics always work with classes, so when working with a generic like this, you need to use the class version of each type. Since Java automatically converts an int value to an Integer object value via autoboxing, there really shouldn't be any difference in your code other than the name of the type used.

Comment: No, good, bad, or indifferent, they only work with class types.

Answer (score 5):

Generics works only for Objects, you have to have overloaded methods for primitive arrays.
(In which you can switch to Integer[], Boolean[] and so on)

Answer (score 4):

Change your array types and variables to `Integer` instead of `int`. Also, make your `checkArray` method static.

```
public class MWE
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Integer[] test1 , test2;
        test1 = new Integer[ 2 ];
        test2 = new Integer[ 2 ];
        checkArray( test1 , test2 );
    }

    private static < T > boolean checkArray( T[] check , T[] test )
    {
        if ( check.length != test.length )
            return false;

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < check.length ; i++ )
            if ( check[ i ] != test[ i ] )
                return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, generics only work with Objects, so technically you could switch to using `Integer[]`, `Boolean[]` etc.

However, note that `Integer[]` and `Boolean[]` extend `Object[]`. Making this method generic actually has little benefit, since `T` will always be inferred to at least be `Object`. For example, the following still compiles:

```
Integer[] test1 = new Integer[2];
Boolean[] test2 = new Boolean[2];
checkArray(test1,test2);
```

The caller would need to specify the type parameter for the check to work:

```
this.<Integer>checkArray(test1,test2); //compile error
```